# Notation on differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

[image]

This is a homework problem. Could anyone tell me the meaning of the symbols $i_{X},i_{Y}$ here?
Thanks a lot.

Also, does $\Omega^{*}(M)$ here mean the exterior algebra bundle on the manifold $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $i_X$ here is the *interior product*, which is just contraction with the first slot: for a $k$-form $\omega$, $i_X \omega$ is the $k-1$-form defined by $i_X \omega(Y_2,\ldots,Y_k) = \omega(X,Y_2,\ldots,Y_k).$

On the second point, you're basically right: $\Omega^*(M)$ usually refers to the *space of sections of* the exterior algebra of the cotangent bundle, i.e. $\Omega^*(M) = \Gamma(M, \Lambda T^*M)$ where $\Lambda T^*M = \oplus_{k=0}^m \Lambda^k (T^*M).$ That is, $\Omega^*(M)$ is just the space of all (smooth global) differential forms (possibly of mixed order) on $M$.

Comment: So, $di_{X}$ and $i_{X}d$ mean $d\cdot i_{X}$ and $ i_{X} \cdot d$ where $d$ is the standard degree +1 antiderivation?

Comment: @AritroPathak: they mean the compositions $d \circ i_X, i_X \circ d.$

Comment: Yes sorry for the wrong tex command, I meant $\circ$ when I wrote $\cdot$.